# convert one dimension index to two dimension index

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have index = 25 and I want to convert it to a 2d index with five rows and seven columns. How can I do that?

So far, I have came up with:

```
var index = 25;
var row = 5;
var col = 7;
var twod_row = (index % row)-1 
var twod_col = (index % col)-1
```

Can you help me figure out how to solve this?

Comment: What is a *2-D index*?

Comment: You're going to have to explain the problem, the mapping between the two more thoroughly to make people understand, even supplying a list of examples would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `row`, you could use the integer value of the division by `cols`, and for `col`, you could use the remainder value with `cols`.

```js
function getPosition(index, cols) {
    return {
        row: Math.floor(index / cols),
        col: index % cols
    };
}

console.log(getPosition(0, 7));
console.log(getPosition(1, 7));
console.log(getPosition(2, 7));
console.log(getPosition(7, 7));
console.log(getPosition(25, 7));
console.log(getPosition(34, 7));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: does you solution pass for index 0 , 1  and 34

Comment: 2-d  array index

Answer (score 0):

`Y` represents the index of the row in the 2-D array, and can be obtained by a simple division. `X` represents the index of the where the 'element' should be placed on that specific row.

I have also added a check to see if the input index exceeds the size of the array.

```js
const getNewValues = (idx, row = 5, col = 7) => {  
  const Y = Math.floor(idx/ col); 
  const X = idx % col;
  
  if (Y > (row - 1)) {
    return 'Index exceeds array size!';
  }
  
  return { X, Y }; 
  
}

console.log(getNewValues(0));
console.log(getNewValues(1));
console.log(getNewValues(25));
console.log(getNewValues(34));
console.log(getNewValues(50));
```

Comment: Please add explanation. You are answering for readers and not just for OP

Comment: does you solution pass for index 0 , 1  and 34

Comment: While this code snippet may be the correct solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve quality of your post. Remember that you're answering for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons behind your code suggestion.